# Assignment to variables

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, command-substitution

I was trying to devise a solution to a different question asked on the site and came across this curious issue.  Here is the set of commands that I issued:

```
$ foo=82a9948422
$ echo $foo
82a9948422
$ echo $foo | sed 's/./&\
/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'
3
$ count=`echo $foo | sed 's/./&\
/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
$ echo $count
1
$
```

Notice how the number of unique characters in the variable is 3 but when I assign it to a variable, it reports the count as 1.  I'm puzzled.  Can someone explain the discrepancy please?

Comment: This has to do with how backticks handle whitespace in the output of the commands inside them. I got the correct result (3) by using the `$()` construct instead. The backtick form fails during the sorting step (the characters are never split in the first place). As to why this is so, you'll have to wait for someone more knowledgeable to answer.

Comment: Double your backslashes inside `\`...\`` or use `$(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use backticks for command substitutions: the expansion rules are tricky and not completely consistent across shells. Use `$(…)` instead; it has exactly the same meaning, but an intuitive and portable syntax. You don't need to use any special quoting; the matching close parenthesis determines the end of the command and that's it. In the rare case when the command starts with an opening parenthesis, put a space to avoid confusion with arithmetic expansion (e.g.. `variable=$( (foo; bar) || qux )`).

```
count=$(echo $foo | sed 's/./&\
/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -1 | awk '{print $1}')
```

or

```
count=$(echo $foo | sed 's/./&\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | awk 'NR==1 {print $1}')
```

Comment: Seconded... and another advantage of using command substitution parens() is that they can be nested arbitrarily.